# How to define conditional distribution in terms of expectation value

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\Omega', \mathcal{A}')$ be a random variable.

So usually conditional probability is defined via conditional expectation as
$\mathbb{P}(A|Y):=\mathbb{E}[\chi_A|Y]$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$.

I am wondering now how the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(X|Y)$ for a random variable $X$ is defined via a conditional expectation? Since $X$ is not fixed to a specific set $A$ I dont know how to go on about this.

Comment: $P(X | Y)$ is sort of a meaningless notation. If you want the conditional distribution, it is usually defined as the (random) measure $B \mapsto P(X \in B | Y)$, where $B$ is a Borel set. Since $\{X \in B\}$ is an event you can use the conditional probability definition you had before.

Comment: Why is it meaningless? Would it be more meaninfgul if we condition on some specific Event Y=y

Comment: The issue isn't conditioning on the event $\{Y = y\}$ (in fact, doing so is problematic if $P(Y = y) = 0$). The issue is that we talk about probabilities of events, not of random variables. So $P(X)$ is undefined, but since $\{X \in B\}$ is an event, $P(X \in B)$ is well-defined for any Borel set $B$.

Comment: But we often talk about for instance $\mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}(X\in \cdot)$ and this makes perfectly sense because this is just a (set valued) function, a (probability) measure. If we have some function $f$, it also makes sense to talk about $f$ and not just about  $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't understand that is what your notation meant. At any rate, the conditional distribution is just the (random) measure $$\mathbb P_{X | Y}(B) = \mathbb P[X \in B \,|\, Y].$$

Comment: but what does that then mean regarding the conditional expectation? How can I derive the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(X\in \cdot|Y)$ from the conditional expectation via indicator functions?

Comment: $$\mathbb P [X \in B \, | \, Y] = \mathbb E[\chi_{\{X \in B\}} \,|\, Y] =  \mathbb E[\chi_{B}(X) \,|\, Y].$$That is about the most you can say, unless you have more information about $X$ and $Y$ and so forth.